# Capture video on android NO RECORDING

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, video-capture

I've been reading the android api for capture video and reading some code and I haven't been able to found a method that give me the frame captured and then work with it, for example send it across wifi or something like that. 
There is a feature, on android, that allow me capture the frame but no record 
it in a file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have 2 solutions. First one is use the `MediaRecorder` object and in the `setOutputFile()` function, pass as parameter a socket descriptor, this way permits read the data from a socket. The second one is use a preview callback and intercept the frame with `onPreviewFrame()` function.